# Getting: _start_agent:18: no such file or directory: /root/.ssh/environment

Tags: ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Whenever I log into a box, I'm getting

```
_start_agent:18: no such file or directory: /root/.ssh/environment-8c5f0414d6b3
chmod: /root/.ssh/environment-8c5f0414d6b3: No such file or directory
_start_agent:.:20: no such file or directory: /root/.ssh/environment-8c5f0414d6b3
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error, in my case, resulted from using Chezmoi to distribute dotfiles that configured (in `~/.zshrc`) ohmyzsh with,

```
plugins=(ssh-agent)
```

The ssh-agent plugin for ohmyzsh, produces this rather obscure if the directory for `~/.ssh` does not exist for the user you're trying to log into. In my case, this was a result of a containerization.